# Elements in Flexbox dont move, when i shrink the size of my window

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want that the div panel_pricing-table becomes an flexbox so that all elements in it stay in this box also when i make my window smaller. My problem is that the elements in the flexbox wont shrink, if i make my browser window smaller. The mistake is in CSS but i dont find it. Can you help me pls?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFcGt.png)

Here is my HTML:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: #3a86ff;
    
}

.panel_pricing-table{
width:80%;
margin: 0 auto;
 display :flex;
  transform: translateY(70%);
 background-color: aliceblue;
 min-width: 40px;
 max-width: 34200px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Price Tiers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="panel_pricing-table">

        <div class="pricing-plan">
            <img src="icons/icon1.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
            <h2 class="pricing-header">Personal</h2> 
            <ul class="pricing-features">
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Custom domains</li>
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity</li>
            </ul>
            <span class="pricing-price">Free</span>
            <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Sign up</a>
        </div>

        <div class="pricing-plan">
            <img src="icons/icon2.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
            <h2 class="pricing-header">Small team</h2>
            <ul class="pricing-features">
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Never sleeps</li>
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Multiple workers for more powerful apps</li>
            </ul>
            <span class="pricing-price">$150</span>
            <a href="#/" class="pricing-button is-featured">Free trial</a>
        </div>

        <div class="pricing-plan">
            <img src="icons/icon3.png" alt="" class="pricing-img">
            <h2 class="pricing-header">Enterprise</h2>
            <ul class="pricing-features">
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Dedicated</li>
                <li class="pricing-features-item">Simple horizontal scalability</li>
            </ul>
            <span class="pricing-price">$400</span>
            <a href="#/" class="pricing-button">Free trial</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what you're trying to achieve? Should the elements inside the flexbox break into another row?

Comment: No the elements should not break into another row. So i dont to use flex:wrap . The elements should stay in the same row just shrink down.

Comment: What do you mean by "shrinking"? Everything in it should get smaller?

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake when i uploaded my HTML Code.There are images in HTML but you cannot see them here because of the relativ file path. If i add Images ,the text and everything else will not become smaller, when i make my window smaller.

Answer (score 0):

you should learn **responsive_html**, it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css file. You have to make your image size small
For my reference, i have kept the width 80 you can keep whatever you want

```
.pricing-img{
    width:80%
  }
```

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. There are images in HTML but you cannot see them here because of the relativ file path. If i add Images the text and everything else will not shrink.

Comment: Send your's screenshot

Comment: I added the Screenshot above

Comment: You have to adjust the size of the added image. Just add width property to **.pricing-img** class

Comment: Yeah ty now it works. But why does it work hahah ? The img is in the flexbox , so why do i have to manual set the width of img so that it stays always in the box?

Comment: Your image had some default width. When you add your image to any container which is having some amount of width, lets say 500px. If your image width is more than 500px than it will ignore the restricted width of container and takes its own default width eg. 700px. Now when you set the width of your image to some percentage lets say 50% then it will adjust itself to the container's width. Like it will always take 50% of the container whenever we adjust the size of the window. This way the image stays in the box.

Answer (score 0):

A (in my opinion quite dirty) way to shrink the elements would be to use `transform: scale(x)` with x being smaller than 1.

What you probably want to do is use smaller font-sizes on smaller viewports.
A good starting point to learn more about responsiveness in css would be to read about media queries: [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)